# CSS to make tables equal height, including stretching their rowspan vertical headers?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have several tables with a vertical header cell on the left which is set to span across all rows using `rowspan`.

The vertical header has its own `background-color`.

I want the tables to all be the same height, including "stretching" the vertical header (or at least stretching its `background-color`), ideally without editing the HTML markup of the table itself (e.g. adding fake/empty rows), and definitely without JavaScript.

## Demo Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/97owvn6f/3/

```css
#tables {
  background-color: purple;
}

table {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.vertical-header {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="tables">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th class="vertical-header" rowspan="3">A</th>
        <th colspan="4">My Short Table</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Small widget</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Medium widget</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="vertical-header" rowspan="11">B</th>
        <th colspan="3">My Tall Table</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Small widget</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Medium widget</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Other widget</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Other widget</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Other widget</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Other widget</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Other widget</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Other widget</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>Other widget</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Other widget</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**What I currently have:**
[image]

**What I want:**
[image]

Comment: [mcve] in your question please

Comment: display: flex; to your #tables element

Comment: @alotropico try that in the JSFiddle link - it doesn't match the desired result.

Comment: @j08691 Did you miss the giant JSFiddle link?

Comment: No, but you're required to post your code in your question, not only on a third party site. Jsfiddle could be inaccessible, sold, or blocked for a variety of reasons, at which point your question loses all value to future visitors. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312548/616443

Comment: @j08691 I understand; I wasn't aware it was a real rule since I see so many other questions linking to JSFiddle. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: flex;` in the container fixes the height of the tables to fill the available space, the problem is the tbody doesn't stretch to the total height because it only adopts the size of its tr elements.

A possible workaround is to make the pink stripe with a linear-gradient as background for the tables:

```css
#tables {
  background-color: purple;
  display: flex;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-right: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, pink 0%, pink 34px, lightblue 34px);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.vertical-header {
  width: 14px; /* +20px of padding = 34px for the pink stripe */
}
```

```html
<div id="tables">
  <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="vertical-header" rowspan="3">A</th>
            <th colspan="4">My Short Table</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Small widget</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Medium widget</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="vertical-header" rowspan="11">B</th>
            <th colspan="3">My Tall Table</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Small widget</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Medium widget</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Other widget</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Other widget</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Other widget</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Other widget</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>Other widget</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>Other widget</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>Other widget</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Other widget</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Clever idea, just a shame it won't automatically accommodate changes to the width of the vertical label column. Could there be a solution where the last `<tr>` element of each table is forced to stretch to fill all the available height?

Comment: I don't think it can be done with this markup, not even using js. The last tr won't expand more than the total sum height of the other trs. You could expand all the table, but then the data td would also be too tall. If you need a flexible width for the vertical-header you can use a div outside the table for it. Let me know if you want a code suggestion for it

Comment: Using js you could also tune the gradient-background's width or use :after :before elements for the background and also adjust their width with js